# cant save json.decode to share preferences in flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I have list, I want to save in sharepreferences,
`setString('key',json.encode(temporaryData));`

When I try to get this value, only show `Instance of Future<dynamic>`
but when i print that json.encode show it value

```
[{"name":"Stranger","birthDate":"","idCardNum":"-1","currentTime":1593598133479,"imageFlag":1,"imageName":"-1_1_1593598133479.png","type":-1,"tempratrue":"36.3","mask":0}]
```

```
Future<SharedPreferences> storage() {
    return SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  }

  void setTempData(String temp) async {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = await storage();
    await sharedPreferences.setString('datas', temp);
  }

  getTempData(String key) async {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = await storage();
    await sharedPreferences.get(key);
  }

  _getTemp() async {
    DateTime start = DateTime.now().subtract(Duration(seconds: 5));
    DateTime end = DateTime.now();
    Map data = {'pass': '123456', 'startTime': '$start', 'endTime': '$end'};
    var response = await http.post('$urlApiQr:8080/newFindRecords', body: data);
    var jsonData = json.decode(response.body);
    var jsEnc = json.encode(response.body);
    TempJson tempJson = TempJson.fromJson(jsonData);
    var parse = json.decode(tempJson.config);
    setState(() {
      dataList = parse;
      temporaryData = dataList.toSet().toList();
      setTempData(json.encode(temporaryData));

      //try to print value
      print('$start and $end');
      print(parse);
      print(getTempData('datas'));
    });
  }
```

Is there a solution to my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE 2.0**

you have to add `await` anywhere your are requesting value from a Future.. as the below method return a Future as you can see from your error, just add await keyword from where you are requesting a value,
for example
`print(await getTempData(key));`

**UPDATE**

return keyword missing

```
  getTempData(String key) async {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = await storage();
    //you missed the return keyword here
    return await sharedPreferences.get(key);
  }
```

**original answer**

dont miss the await keyword

```
var thestring = await sp.getString('the_key');

var theJsonObj = json.decode(thestring);
```

this is my assumption, please post more code